# Change type column in django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

## Fill table

```
mydata.append({
            'bool_access': True,
            'path': path
        })
table = mytable(data=mydata)

----> render table
```

## Table

```
class mytable(tables.Table):

    path = tables.Column(verbose_name='My path')

    # path = tables.LinkColumn('page_web', args=[A('path')],verbose_name='My path')

    bool_access = ""

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'}
        sequence = ('path')
```

## Wanted

I want that if a add a row in my data with `bool_access` at "True" that the column type for `path` is `tables.LinkColumn` and else if `bool_access` at "False" the column type is `tables.Column`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this, but I think the most straightforward one is using a [`TemplateColumn`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn):

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):

    path = tables.TemplateColumn(
        verbose_name='My path', 
        template_code="""{% if record.bool_access %}<a href="{% url "page_web" record.path %}">{{ record.path }}</a>{% else %}{{ record.path }}{% endif %}""")

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed'}
        sequence = ('path')
```